# Grails: How to merge pdf's when 1 is generated from HTML

Tags: pdf, grails, merge, rendering

So I've got a situation where I need to merge a cover sheet to another pdf document. The user uploads the document but the cover sheet is dynamically generated using the rendering plugin and a grails template.

What I want to do is generate the cover sheet as a pdf without rendering it to the browser and just covert it to bytes. My code is like this at the moment:

```
PDFMergerUtility mergePdf = new PDFMergerUtility() 
                  mergePdf.addSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(params.documentContent.content.bytes)) 
                  mergePdf.addSource(renderPdf(template: "generateExamCoverSheet", 
                                                             filename: null, 
                                                             model: [examItem: ei, 
                                                                        reqMaterials: reqMaterials, 
                                                                        type: 'standard'])) 
                  mergePdf.mergeDocuments();
```

Obviously the second addSource where I'm using renderPdf() is wrong and is just rendering it to the browser, but I don't know how to generate a pdf without rendering it. Any ideas how I can turn a grails template into a pdf then use the bytes?

**EDIT: Thanks to Joshua Moore, who pushed me in the right direction. It might not be the best but heres what is working for me:**

```
String documentName = params.documentContent.content.fileItem.getName()
String fileName = FilenameUtils.getBaseName(documentName)
String fileExtension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(documentName)
File originalFile = File.createTempFile(fileName, '.'+fileExtension)
File mergedFile = null
params.documentContent.content.fileItem.write(originalFile)

ByteArrayOutputStream coverSheet = pdfRenderingService.render(controller:'examDefinition', 
                       template: "generateExamCoverSheet",
                       model: [examItem: ei, 
                               reqMaterials: reqMaterials, 
                               type: 'standard'])

ByteArrayInputStream coverSheetIS = new ByteArrayInputStream(coverSheet.toByteArray())
                PDFMergerUtility mergePdf = new PDFMergerUtility()
                mergePdf.addSource(coverSheetIS)
                mergePdf.addSource(originalFile)
                mergePdf.setDestinationFileName('theFile.pdf')
                mergePdf.mergeDocuments()
                mergedFile = new File(mergePdf.getDestinationFileName())
```

Ultimately I wanted to save the file in a BLOB field, PDFMergerUtility doesn't seem to have a method that returns a temp file, so after I save the file (code not shown here) I then just say mergedFile.delete(). It may be ugly but it's working XD.

Thanks, 
Billy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://gpc.github.io/grails-rendering/docs/manual/guide/single.html) you should be able to render the second one as a byte array using the PDF rendering service.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = pdfRenderingService.render(template: "generateExamCoverSheet", 
  model: [examItem: ei, 
    reqMaterials: reqMaterials, 
    type: 'standard']
)

mergePdf.addSource(bytes)
```

Comment: Thanks Josh, this got me unstuck at least. I've edited my original post with what is now working.

Comment: Glad you got it working. Your edited solution seems perfectly reasonable too. (fyi, you should accept and upvote the answer)